# jquery preventing submit delay

Tags: jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#reg-username").keyup(checkusername);
   $("#reg-password").keyup(checkpassword);
   $("#email").keyup(checkemail);
   $("#confirm-email").keyup(checkconfirmemail);
   $("#register-day").keyup(checkday);
   $("#register-month").change(disableselect).change();
   $("#register-years").keyup(checkyears);
   $(document).click(function() {
        $('#contact-form').submit(function(){
            checkusername();
            checkpassword();
            checkemail();
            checkconfirmemail();
            checkday();
            checkselect();
            checkyears();
            $("input[name='gender'").change(checkgender).change();
            if(!checkusername() || !checkpassword() || !checkemail() || !checkconfirmemail() || !checkday() || !checkselect() || !checkyears()){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#othersubmit-result").css('color', 'red');
            $("#othersubmit-result").html('sumbit not requirements.');
            return false;
            }else{
            $("#othersubmit-result").css('color', 'green');
            $("#othersubmit-result").html('sumbit passed.');
            return true;
            }
            });
        });
   });
```

i am making a validation client side form , this is the jquery but if the form dont fill in properly and i press submit it somehow hang or delay a bit , like loading a while , i guess is i put too much function on the submit ???

how should i prevent that happen ?

Comment: are all those checks on the client or server side?

Comment: checkusername();
            checkpassword();
            checkemail();
            checkconfirmemail();
            checkday();
            checkselect();
            checkyears();

Need to see those functions to learn more about the delay.

Comment: On each document click, you are binding a new form submit event which bind a new change event, and so on... Dont do that

Comment: so i do a refresh page if it do not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that you're binding the event multiple times. The following code of yours,

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#contact-form').submit(function(){
        // ... Code Here ...
    });
});
```

will attach a submit event handler *every time* the document is clicked. If you click the document 10 times before submitting, then 10 submit event handlers will be attached and triggered when you submit the form.

If `#contact-form` exists on the page when it is loaded, you can simply change it to:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(){
    // ... Code Here ...
});
```

Otherwise, you could use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and change it to:

```
$(document).on("submit", '#contact-form', function(){
    // ... Code Here ...
});
```

Also, as @AWolff pointed out, you have a `.change` event nested inside the submit event. This should likewise be in the `document.ready` function on its own:

```
$("input[name='gender'").change(checkgender).change();
```

The selector in that line also has an error and should have an ending bracket: `input[name='gender']`

Comment: Dont forget the nested change event :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Oh! I didn't even notice that. Thanks for pointing it out. I added it to the answer.

Comment: thank but it still delay if i pressed a few times , isit normal ? or i should never put so many function on the submit ? i like the on submit part.

Comment: @user3233074 It depends what the functions do. If all of the `check` functions are making blocking ajax calls, then I'd imagine that it would be very slow. Other than the errors pointed out in my answer, I can only guess what is causing the slowness since you haven't included the implementation of the functions being called.